# Setting width of VerticalLayout in Vaadin Designer is IGNORED if object is referenced in corresponding java code

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

If one creates a vertical layout class using Vaadin Designer (in Vaadin 14) and sets its width to some fixed value (eg 3%) *and* one has a reference to that vertical layout component in the corresponding java code, Vaadin will IGNORE the width setting. Curiously, this bug dissappears if one does NOT reference the vertical layout class in the java code. Here's a working test case to illustrate the bug. For now, my "hack" has been to avoid referencing the object in my java code, or if I must, then I think I need to explicitly reset the width logic in the java code itself. Any thoughts?

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-horizontal-layout.js';

class UiTestview extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
<style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
<vaadin-horizontal-layout class="content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <vaadin-vertical-layout id="left" style="width: 3%;background-color:blue">
 <label>left label</label>
 </vaadin-vertical-layout>
 <label style="flex-grow: 1;background-color:red">Label</label>
</vaadin-horizontal-layout>
`;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'ui-testview';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(UiTestview.is, UiTestview);
```

and the corresponding java code:

```
package org.vaadin;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.template.Id;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.templatemodel.TemplateModel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate;


/**
 * A Designer generated component for the ui-testview template.
 *
 * Designer will add and remove fields with @Id mappings but
 * does not overwrite or otherwise change this file.
 */
@Route("testview")
@Tag("ui-testview")
@JsModule("./src/ui-testview.js")
public class UiTestview extends PolymerTemplate<UiTestview.UiTestviewModel> {


    @Id("left")
    private VerticalLayout left;

    /**
     * Creates a new UiTestview.
     */
    public UiTestview() {

    }

    /**
     * This model binds properties between UiTestview and ui-testview
     */
    public interface UiTestviewModel extends TemplateModel {
        // Add setters and getters for template properties here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be related to this known issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the Java-side of Vaadin (at least in Vaadin 14) does not know about any initial client-side state from the template. That's why Java-getters will often not return values set in your template. Furthermore, `VerticalLayout` sets `setWidth("100%")` in its constructor which may actually override a width set in your template once you map it to your template. This is something that has been improved in Vaadin 18. I doubt this will be backported to Vaadin 14.

Comment: In what way has this been improved in 18? I'm using Vaadin 23 and I'm still seeing this exact same issue.

Comment: `Starting from Vaadin 18, the initial attribute values in the template are reflected to the server side state when @Id mapping components.` But I assume this only applies to official attributes of the Web Component and not e.g. the width set via `style`. Also this likely won't work for e.g. `Button#getText()` as it's not set via attribute but instead as a child (text) node: `<vaadin-button>Label</vaadin-button>`. But yeah, still not ideal. I'm sure you can work around all that, but I decided to roll my own solution that works more like the old Declarative UI from Vaadin 8.